# element with display flex and width 100% caused element move horizontally

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I tried to understand what is the main reason and how to fix my issue here. I have one element with fixed width and 2 children element following as 100%. under the most inner element display set as `flex`. Then I am able to move the element horizontal. anyway I can fix the issue by just modify the class `section` and `panel`? I would like to keep margin as 5px under panel with or without scrollbar displayed
[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/imio24/pen/qBXBgdp)

```css
.section{
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width : 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  
}

.panel{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  display:flex; 
}
  
.App {
  width: 570px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='App'>
    <div class='section'>
      <div class='panel'>
          <span> label </span>
          <input />
          <span> label </span>
          <input />
          <span> label </span>
          <input />
          <span> label </span>
          <input />
          <p>real-world studies published Wednesday confirm that the immune protection offered by two doses of Pfizer's Covid-19 vaccine drops off after two months or so, although protection against severe disease, hospitalization and death remains strong. The studies,
            from Israel and from Qatar and published in the New England Journal of Medicine, support arguments that even fully vaccinated people need to maintain precautions against infection. One study from Israel covered 4,800 health care workers and
            showed antibody levels wane rapidly after two doses of vaccine 'especially among men, among persons 65 years of age or older, and among persons with immunosuppression.' Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000
            deaths among seniors Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000 deaths among seniors 'We conducted this prospective longitudinal cohort study involving health care workers at Sheba Medical Center, a large tertiary
            medical center in Israel,' Sheba's Dr. Gili Regev-Yochay and colleagues wrote. The researchers noted that levels of so-called neutralizing antibodies -- the immune system's first line of defense against infection -- correlate with protection
            against infection, but for this study they studied only antibody levels.
          </p>
          <p>real-world studies published Wednesday confirm that the immune protection offered by two doses of Pfizer's Covid-19 vaccine drops off after two months or so, although protection against severe disease, hospitalization and death remains strong. The studies,
            from Israel and from Qatar and published in the New England Journal of Medicine, support arguments that even fully vaccinated people need to maintain precautions against infection. One study from Israel covered 4,800 health care workers and
            showed antibody levels wane rapidly after two doses of vaccine 'especially among men, among persons 65 years of age or older, and among persons with immunosuppression.' Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000
            deaths among seniors Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000 deaths among seniors 'We conducted this prospective longitudinal cohort study involving health care workers at Sheba Medical Center, a large tertiary
            medical center in Israel,' Sheba's Dr. Gili Regev-Yochay and colleagues wrote. The researchers noted that levels of so-called neutralizing antibodies -- the immune system's first line of defense against infection -- correlate with protection
            against infection, but for this study they studied only antibody levels.
          </p>
          <p>real-world studies published Wednesday confirm that the immune protection offered by two doses of Pfizer's Covid-19 vaccine drops off after two months or so, although protection against severe disease, hospitalization and death remains strong. The studies,
            from Israel and from Qatar and published in the New England Journal of Medicine, support arguments that even fully vaccinated people need to maintain precautions against infection. One study from Israel covered 4,800 health care workers and
            showed antibody levels wane rapidly after two doses of vaccine 'especially among men, among persons 65 years of age or older, and among persons with immunosuppression.' Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000
            deaths among seniors Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000 deaths among seniors 'We conducted this prospective longitudinal cohort study involving health care workers at Sheba Medical Center, a large tertiary
            medical center in Israel,' Sheba's Dr. Gili Regev-Yochay and colleagues wrote. The researchers noted that levels of so-called neutralizing antibodies -- the immune system's first line of defense against infection -- correlate with protection
            against infection, but for this study they studied only antibody levels.
          </p>
          <p>
            real-world studies published Wednesday confirm that the immune protection offered by two doses of Pfizer's Covid-19 vaccine drops off after two months or so, although protection against severe disease, hospitalization and death remains strong. The studies,
            from Israel and from Qatar and published in the New England Journal of Medicine, support arguments that even fully vaccinated people need to maintain precautions against infection. One study from Israel covered 4,800 health care workers and
            showed antibody levels wane rapidly after two doses of vaccine 'especially among men, among persons 65 years of age or older, and among persons with immunosuppression.' Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000
            deaths among seniors Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000 deaths among seniors 'We conducted this prospective longitudinal cohort study involving health care workers at Sheba Medical Center, a large tertiary
            medical center in Israel,' Sheba's Dr. Gili Regev-Yochay and colleagues wrote. The researchers noted that levels of so-called neutralizing antibodies -- the immune system's first line of defense against infection -- correlate with protection
            against infection, but for this study they studied only antibody levels.
          </p>
          <p>
            real-world studies published Wednesday confirm that the immune protection offered by two doses of Pfizer's Covid-19 vaccine drops off after two months or so, although protection against severe disease, hospitalization and death remains strong. The studies,
            from Israel and from Qatar and published in the New England Journal of Medicine, support arguments that even fully vaccinated people need to maintain precautions against infection. One study from Israel covered 4,800 health care workers and
            showed antibody levels wane rapidly after two doses of vaccine 'especially among men, among persons 65 years of age or older, and among persons with immunosuppression.' Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000
            deaths among seniors Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000 deaths among seniors 'We conducted this prospective longitudinal cohort study involving health care workers at Sheba Medical Center, a large tertiary
            medical center in Israel,' Sheba's Dr. Gili Regev-Yochay and colleagues wrote. The researchers noted that levels of so-called neutralizing antibodies -- the immune system's first line of defense against infection -- correlate with protection
            against infection, but for this study they studied only antibody levels.
          </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: i want to the context inside `panel` does not move horizontially

Comment: @jacobcan118 you want all element on panel in 1 line and no scroll horizontal?

Answer (score 0):

I don't now what you want, but mybe this can help you.
use css "grid" to handle your problem.

```css
.section{
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width : 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  
}

.panel{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
  
.App {
  width: 570px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='App'>
    <div class='section'>
      <div class='panel'>
          <div>
              <span> label </span>
              <input />
          </div>
          <div>
              <span> label </span>
              <input />
          </div>
          <div>
              <span> label </span>
              <input />
          </div>
          <div>
              <span> label </span>
              <input />
          </div>
          <div>
              <span> label </span>
              <input />
          </div>
       </div/>
       <div class="panel">
          <p>real-world studies published Wednesday confirm that the immune protection offered by two doses of Pfizer's Covid-19 vaccine drops off after two months or so, although protection against severe disease, hospitalization and death remains strong. The studies,
            from Israel and from Qatar and published in the New England Journal of Medicine, support arguments that even fully vaccinated people need to maintain precautions against infection. One study from Israel covered 4,800 health care workers and
            showed antibody levels wane rapidly after two doses of vaccine 'especially among men, among persons 65 years of age or older, and among persons with immunosuppression.' Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000
            deaths among seniors Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000 deaths among seniors 'We conducted this prospective longitudinal cohort study involving health care workers at Sheba Medical Center, a large tertiary
            medical center in Israel,' Sheba's Dr. Gili Regev-Yochay and colleagues wrote. The researchers noted that levels of so-called neutralizing antibodies -- the immune system's first line of defense against infection -- correlate with protection
            against infection, but for this study they studied only antibody levels.
          </p>
          <p>real-world studies published Wednesday confirm that the immune protection offered by two doses of Pfizer's Covid-19 vaccine drops off after two months or so, although protection against severe disease, hospitalization and death remains strong. The studies,
            from Israel and from Qatar and published in the New England Journal of Medicine, support arguments that even fully vaccinated people need to maintain precautions against infection. One study from Israel covered 4,800 health care workers and
            showed antibody levels wane rapidly after two doses of vaccine 'especially among men, among persons 65 years of age or older, and among persons with immunosuppression.' Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000
            deaths among seniors Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000 deaths among seniors 'We conducted this prospective longitudinal cohort study involving health care workers at Sheba Medical Center, a large tertiary
            medical center in Israel,' Sheba's Dr. Gili Regev-Yochay and colleagues wrote. The researchers noted that levels of so-called neutralizing antibodies -- the immune system's first line of defense against infection -- correlate with protection
            against infection, but for this study they studied only antibody levels.
          </p>
          <p>real-world studies published Wednesday confirm that the immune protection offered by two doses of Pfizer's Covid-19 vaccine drops off after two months or so, although protection against severe disease, hospitalization and death remains strong. The studies,
            from Israel and from Qatar and published in the New England Journal of Medicine, support arguments that even fully vaccinated people need to maintain precautions against infection. One study from Israel covered 4,800 health care workers and
            showed antibody levels wane rapidly after two doses of vaccine 'especially among men, among persons 65 years of age or older, and among persons with immunosuppression.' Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000
            deaths among seniors Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000 deaths among seniors 'We conducted this prospective longitudinal cohort study involving health care workers at Sheba Medical Center, a large tertiary
            medical center in Israel,' Sheba's Dr. Gili Regev-Yochay and colleagues wrote. The researchers noted that levels of so-called neutralizing antibodies -- the immune system's first line of defense against infection -- correlate with protection
            against infection, but for this study they studied only antibody levels.
          </p>
          <p>
            real-world studies published Wednesday confirm that the immune protection offered by two doses of Pfizer's Covid-19 vaccine drops off after two months or so, although protection against severe disease, hospitalization and death remains strong. The studies,
            from Israel and from Qatar and published in the New England Journal of Medicine, support arguments that even fully vaccinated people need to maintain precautions against infection. One study from Israel covered 4,800 health care workers and
            showed antibody levels wane rapidly after two doses of vaccine 'especially among men, among persons 65 years of age or older, and among persons with immunosuppression.' Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000
            deaths among seniors Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000 deaths among seniors 'We conducted this prospective longitudinal cohort study involving health care workers at Sheba Medical Center, a large tertiary
            medical center in Israel,' Sheba's Dr. Gili Regev-Yochay and colleagues wrote. The researchers noted that levels of so-called neutralizing antibodies -- the immune system's first line of defense against infection -- correlate with protection
            against infection, but for this study they studied only antibody levels.
          </p>
          <p>
            real-world studies published Wednesday confirm that the immune protection offered by two doses of Pfizer's Covid-19 vaccine drops off after two months or so, although protection against severe disease, hospitalization and death remains strong. The studies,
            from Israel and from Qatar and published in the New England Journal of Medicine, support arguments that even fully vaccinated people need to maintain precautions against infection. One study from Israel covered 4,800 health care workers and
            showed antibody levels wane rapidly after two doses of vaccine 'especially among men, among persons 65 years of age or older, and among persons with immunosuppression.' Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000
            deaths among seniors Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000 deaths among seniors 'We conducted this prospective longitudinal cohort study involving health care workers at Sheba Medical Center, a large tertiary
            medical center in Israel,' Sheba's Dr. Gili Regev-Yochay and colleagues wrote. The researchers noted that levels of so-called neutralizing antibodies -- the immune system's first line of defense against infection -- correlate with protection
            against infection, but for this study they studied only antibody levels.
          </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```